# What are the prerequisites to study Cohen-Macaulay?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

I am doing a reading in advanced algebra and I need some help in Cohen-Macaulay :

My doubts are

1. What are the prerequisites I need to know before knowing what is Cohen-Macaulay? (I know about basic ring theory - up to UFD and Gröbner basis)
2. Which is the best book to study it from? (given my very small background in algebra)

Also some introduction to it would be helpful.

Comment: 1. Basic knowledge of Commutative Algebra. 2. Many good books: Kaplansky, Matsumura, Bruns and Herzog...

Comment: Btw, Cohen-Macaulay what?